# Plotting unrelated plots in a grid with different axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 93711,  1: 93717,  2: 93719,  3: 93731,  4: 93738,  5: 93755,  6: 93758,  7: 93760,  8: 93763},
                  'sex': {0: 'M',  1: 'M',  2: 'F',  3: 'M',  4: 'M',  5: 'F',  6: 'F',  7: 'F',  8: 'M'},
                  'age': {0: 56,  1: 22,  2: 13,  3: 20,  4: 26,  5: 26,  6: 55,  7: 54,  8: 40},
                  'insulin': {0: 31.68,  1: 23.64,  2: 65.64,  3: 127.98,  4: 33.42,  5: 122.46,  6: 32.52,  7: 119.88,  8: 64.68},
                  'totalPF': {0: 22.8,  1: 20.4,  2: 33.4,  3: 31.3,  4: 25.1,  5: 42.6,  6: 43.5,  7: 44.1,  8: 20.2}})
```

I have a dataframe that's like 5000x30 and took a small sample here.

```
      ID sex  age  insulin  totalPF
0  93711   M   56    31.68     22.8
1  93717   M   22    23.64     20.4
2  93719   F   13    65.64     33.4
3  93731   M   20   127.98     31.3
4  93738   M   26    33.42     25.1
5  93755   F   26   122.46     42.6
6  93758   F   55    32.52     43.5
7  93760   F   54   119.88     44.1
8  93763   M   40    64.68     20.2
```

I want to draw

```
sns.lmplot(x='insulin', y='age', hue='sex', data=df)
sns.lmplot(x='totalPF', y='age', hue='sex', data=df)
sns.lmplot(x='insulin', y='totalPF', hue='sex', data=df)
```

and have these plots in a grid with each plot taking the y-axis and x-axis from different columns in my dataframe. I also want it to show two different colors and lines for each sex.
Ideally I can have like 20+ graphs in a nice grid, showing different combinations of axis.
This is all done in Jupyter Notebook btw.

Using a for loop I can make it draw the graphs I want but not in a nice grid.
I also tried playing around with basic matplotlib subplots but it seems like hell to iterate over many columns.
There might also be some way to tidy the dataframe for lmplot and FacetGrid to do all the work, but I've tried a couple things and I'm not getting any closer either.

[Ideally it looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ1M7.png)

Comment: `sns.regplot` + `plt.subplots()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pretty much the desired output using `PairGrid`:

```
x_vars = ['insulin','totalPF']
y_vars = ['age','totalPF']
hue_var = 'sex'

g = sns.PairGrid(data=df, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars, hue=hue_var)
g.map(sns.regplot)
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

Optionally, you could remove the lower right axes to get rid of the superfluous plot.
`g.axes[-1,-1].remove()`

Otherwise, if you'd rather follow @PaulH's comment, which is right on. This is how I would implement:

```
from itertools import product

x_vars = ['insulin','totalPF']
y_vars = ['age','totalPF']
hue_var = 'sex'
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(y_vars), len(x_vars), sharex='col', sharey='row')
for ax,(y,x) in zip(axs.flat,product(y_vars,x_vars)):
    for hue,gr in df.groupby(hue_var):
        print(x,y,hue,ax)
        sns.regplot(x=x,y=y,data=gr,ax=ax,label=hue)
axs[0,0].legend()
```

[image]